# JPA - How can I cascade delete an entity that references itself?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

I have the following entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parameter_choice")
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "listParameterChoicesByParameter",
                query = "SELECT pc FROM ParameterChoice pc WHERE pc.ParameterId = :parameterId")
})

@XmlRootElement
@Cacheable(false)
public class ParameterChoice implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "ParameterChoiceSequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(allocationSize = 1, name = "ParameterChoiceSequenceGenerator", sequenceName = "parameter_choice_id_seq")
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "parameter_id", nullable = false)
    private Integer ParameterId;

    @Column(name = "parent_parameter_choice_id", nullable = true)
    private Integer parentParameterChoiceId;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_parameter_choice_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private List<ParameterChoice> parameterChoices;

    @Column(name = "canonical_name", nullable = false)
    private String canonicalName;

    @Column(name = "ui_only", nullable = false)
    private Boolean uiOnly;
```

Then I create an entity then a second one with the id of the first one as `parentParameterChoiceId`.
When I try to delete the first entity, I get a foreign key constraint error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: update or delete on table "parameter_choice" violates foreign key constraint "fk_parameter_choice_parameter_choice" on table "parameter_choice" Detail: Key (id)=(15) is still referenced from table "parameter_choice"
```

As you can see, I tried `orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE` with no result. Is there a way to cascade delete the first Entity instance with all its sub-entities?

**EDIT**
The code that creates the entities:

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/parameter-choice")
public String addParameterChoice(ParameterChoice parameterChoice) {
    String bodyContent = "";
    String errMessage = "Error in POST: /parameter-choice/.";
    try {
        em.persist(parameterChoice);
        bodyContent = mapper.writeValueAsString(parameterChoice);
        return responseBuilder.buildString(bodyContent, ResponseBuilder.OK);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, errMessage, e);
        return responseBuilder.buildString("errMessage", ResponseBuilder.ERROR);
    }
}
```

And the code to delete an entity:

```
@DELETE
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/parameter-choice/{parameterChoiceId}")
public String deleteParameterChoice(@PathParam("parameterChoiceId") String parameterChoiceId) {
    String bodyContent = "OK";
    ParameterChoice parameterChoice = em.find(ParameterChoice.class, Integer.parseInt(parameterChoiceId));
    em.remove(parameterChoice);
    return responseBuilder.buildString(bodyContent, ResponseBuilder.OK);
}
```

Comment: Show us the code where you create and delete the entities. Also, why do you store the ID of the parent, instead of storing a reference to the parent (and the make it a bidirectional OneToMany)?

Comment: I create the entities with `em.persist(parameterChoice)` and delete them with `em.remove(parameterChoice)`. As for why I store the ID of the parent, I figured it was the way to do it. Is there a better way?

Comment: I also wanted to get all the children when listing the parent.

Comment: No code, no help. The code matters. And yes, there is a better way: make it a bidirectional association, by replacing the parent ID with `@ManyToOne private ParameterChoice parent;`

Comment: I added the code as requested. Regarding the @ManyToOne association, will it help on cascade deletion?

Comment: My guess is that it will, yes.

Comment: Good guess, it seems to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by JB Nizet in the comments, I was missing the ManyToOne association that seems necessary to allow cascade deletion:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_parameter_choice_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private ParameterChoice parentParameterChoice;
```